# Dynamically select based on List of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, select, dynamic

I have a List of columns model as below:

```
    class ColumnSettings
    {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set;}
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    }
```

I have an stored procedure to return users list (GetUserList), and when I query the database, the data is returned with 30 columns.

I dynamically select visible columns in view and pass columns to controller and convert to List of ColumnSettings and set modelData variable.

I want to select those columns that are in modelData variable, something like :

GetUserList.select(s => s.???)

I make problem easier. Suppose I have a grid and I want create Excel file on sever-side. I pass columns to controller, and have a list of columns (List) and then I call SP and get 30 columns, but I don't want all columns and it should be dynamic.

Comment: An you share what you have tried so far? What is the code in the controller and view look like?

Comment: I use Kendo SpreadSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Make your property with dynamic keyword and it will except all over the class which you want make as dynamic.

Comment: How write select?

Comment: viewbag.userlist = GetUserList.select(s => new {s.id, s.name});

Comment: Use the dropdown or dropdownfor as you want respectively and easier for you.

Comment: The select input should be list of ColumnSettings and I pass column name to controller.

Comment: let me explain you more.

Comment: First, bind the data into the viewbag for list and for input you make another property in class where you want to select the record and store into it.

Comment: E.g.
public class MyViewModel
{  
  public string Choice { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChoiceList { get; set; }
  ....
}
MyViewModel.ChoiceList = GetUserList.select(s => new {s.id, s.name});
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Choice, Model.ChoiceList)

above code just for concept of understanding.

Comment: I make problem easier. Suppose I have a grid and I want create Excel file on sever-side. I pass columns to controller, and have a list of columns (List<ColumnSettings>) and then I call SP and get 30 columns, but I don't want all columns and it should be dynamic.

Comment: that means you need just selected column in grid right? as i'm understanding right thing ?

Comment: Yes, because user can select some columns

Comment: can you please give me the screen shot.

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate the method `GetUserList.Select(s => new { ... })` inside other methods returning only the columns that you need for each case? `private List<ColumnSettings> GetUserNameColumn() { return GetUserList.Select(s => new ColumnSettings { Title = s.Name });  }`

Comment: is that multi select or single select ?

Comment: How find and create new ColumnSettings { Title = s.Name }) ? its dyamic

Comment: multiselect, user can select each column seperately

Comment: just pass dynamic model to the view and @model dynamic and in the loop just provide the name of parameter and render them as you want.

Comment: { Title = s.Name,z = s.name, b = s.name }) as example for you and but just pass the dynamic parameter into value it execute you code don't worry about it.

Comment: But @MIDI dynamic property have huge problem when it's not there you expected that result then any time will throw the unexpected result exception.

Comment: by the way all you want to make the separate model for with key and values pair, and when you're looping the record get the column name and then get there respected values .

Comment: @MIDI that will help you out and it will never ever throws you exception any more and if you need code guidance then please let me know i will provide you the code sample.